# How to append a FeatureCollection to a hosted Feature Layer in ArcGIS Enterprise?

Tags: append, arcgis-python-api

This question pertains to `arcgis.gis` in Python, for working with hosted Feature Layers in ArcGIS Enterprise.

I'm using the [enrich_data](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.enrich_data.html) function to calculate a buffer polygon from my input (hosted) point layer, then add population statistics to the resulting polygon - this is working well. I'm not specifying an `output_name`, so the result is an in-memory [FeatureCollection](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurecollection).

Now I wish to append the resulting polygon to an existing polygon layer which is hosted in ArcGIS Enterprise, but I can't figure out how to send the Feature Collection to the existing layer.

I tried the [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) `edit_features` command, which has an `adds` option which expects as input:

```
adds: FeatureSet/List. The array of features to be added
```

I can obtain the FeatureSet from `FeatureCollection.layer.featureSet` but this fails in the `edit_features.add` command with the below error message, which is unclear to me:

[image]

The section `self._mapping[key]` hints that there is an issue with the field mapping between the input and output polygons, but I can't see any options to remap the field names.

TL;DR - how can I append an in-memory FeatureCollection of polygons to a hosted Feature Layer in ArcGIS Enterprise?

Comment: PS [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) mentions an `append` option but this is only available for ArcGIS Online, and I'm working with ArcGIS Enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation around this API is pretty sparse, so I disovered this through a lot of trial+error.

While the [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) page says that it expects to receive a "FeatureSet or List" as input to the `FeatureLayer.edit_features(adds=...)` command, in fact I found that I needed to send the list of features in order to avoid that error message:

`polygonlayer.edit_features(adds=enrich_result.layer.featureSet.features)`